# Fill color to a specific area surrounded by line boundaries

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I have a requirement to fill color on a particular area only on my layout (i.e. I have a chart. That is seperated by a line. I need to fill color to the area that is surrounded by line the segments as showing in image) . I tried a lot. But I couldn't achieve result. Please anybody help me to do this task. Thanks in advance dear friends

[image]

Comment: Please change your title to use normal casing. Caps aren't necessary.

Comment: Moreover, it looks as if you're [shouting at us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing).

Comment: @Carcigenicate yah sure..